# Can I use my PC to mirror an iPod Touch screen like Apple TV?

Tags: ios, windows, appletv, airplay

I'm using an iPod Touch 3 and I saw in the AppStore that it is possible to use it as a controller via Apple TV to play games on it like Modern Combat and Real Racing. Because I don't have neither an Apple TV nor a TV, I was wondering if it could be possible to play these games on my computers monitor via bluetooth or wifi.

Is it is not possible by Apple, maybe there's something in Cydia (under jailbreak) to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Reflector](http://reflectorapp.com/) for PC:

```
Your iPhone or iPad. On your Mac or PC.

AirPlay mirror your iPhone 4S, iPad 2 or the new iPad to any Mac or PC, wirelessly.
```

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Derrp, I knew that.  Sorry, I'll edit now.

Comment: I found this too, but too bad I just have a 3rd gen Ipod Touch.